# Unwanted item in reference list when using crossref with biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

I just started using biber / biblatex, and am having trouble understanding some of its behaviour. I cannot imagine that I am the first to have run into this issue, but I was unable to find a duplicate question.

I am citing several articles that are published in the same journal. To ensure that the journal information is consistent throughout the citations, I made a separate bib entry containing just the journal information. I then cross-reference that entry from the article entries. An example `references.bib` file:

```
@article{myjournal,
    journaltitle={Journal of Interesting Things},
    publisher={Someone}
}

@article{myarticle1,
    crossref={myjournal},
    title={That thing},
    author={Martypants, Susan},
    year={2019},
}

@article{myarticle2,
    crossref={myjournal},
    title={That other thing},
    author={Rofessor, Peter},
    year={2020}
}
```

Now, when I cite both `myarticle1` and `myarticle2` in my document, the reference list contains an extra line with no name, and just the journal information:

[image: output containing unwanted entry]

A minimal working example that produces this output is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\cite{myarticle1,myarticle2}
    
\printbibliography{}
    
\end{document}
```

Interestingly, if I cite only one of the two articles, the "empty" journal item does not appear. (i.e., replacing `\cite{myarticle1,myarticle2}` with `\cite{myarticle1}` results in a reference list of one item instead of three.)

**Workaround solutions:** I can copy-paste the journal info into every paper, and remove the crossref. However, if I later want to change some information about the journal (e.g., add an address of the publisher), I'd have to go through all the entries. Alternatively, I can remove the entry manually from the `.bbl` file, which also results in the desired output. Neither of these solutions are quite satisfactory to me.

**Question:** What is the preferred way to structure the `.bib` so that (a) I don't have to type and maintain duplicate journal information, and (b) the journal entry does not appear as a separate item in the references list, unless explicitly cited?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is an internal mechanic, governed by `mincrossrefs`, which is by default set to 2. This means, if you cite an item with a crossref to another item once, nothing happens. As soon as you cite another item with a crossref to the same item, the crossref-item will also be cited. In your `biblatex`-call, just set `mincrossrefs=99` and this behaviour should stop.

Comment: You can also add `options={skipbib=true},` to the parent entry.

Comment: The `@xdata` entry type is also useful: it acts as a data container for inheritance, and does not print. Example from the manual, p 141: `@XData{hup,
publisher = {Harvard University Press},
location = {Cambridge, Mass.},
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `crossref` field is about more than just data inheritance. It is also about establishing a certain parent-child relation between entries (cf. the `xref` field, which only models this parent-child relation without data inheritance).

One feature of this parent-child relation is that a  parent entry is automatically added to the bibliography if it is referred to by a certain number of children (even if it is not cited explicitly). The exact number of child references can be controlled with the `mincrossrefs` option. Its default value is `2`, meaning that a parent entry is added to the bibliography if it is referred to by at least two (different) child entries. That is the case in your example: `myjournal` is referenced by `myarticle1` and `myarticle2`.

One way around that would be to set `mincrossrefs` to a higher (maybe unreasonably high) value such as `999` as suggested by [Manuel Weinkauf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/56717/manuel-weinkauf) in the [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560565/unwanted-item-in-reference-list-when-using-crossref-with-biber#comment1413736_560565).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, mincrossrefs=999]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myjournal,
  journaltitle = {Journal of Interesting Things},
  publisher    = {Someone},
}
@article{myarticle1,
  crossref = {myjournal},
  title    = {That thing},
  author   = {Martypants, Susan},
  year     = {2019},
}
@article{myarticle2,
  crossref = {myjournal},
  title    = {That other thing},
  author   = {Rofessor, Peter},
  year     = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{myarticle1,myarticle2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

An alternative would be to tell `biblatex` that `myjournal` is only a data container and not an entry that could appear in the bibliography in its own right. That is done by adding `options = {dataonly},` to the entry. This is not unlike [Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182648/cicada)'s [suggestion of `options={skipbib=true},`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560565/unwanted-item-in-reference-list-when-using-crossref-with-biber#comment1413900_560565), but slightly more rigorous (since it will also avoid label creation, which fails here anyway, to be fair). With this solution `myjournal` doesn't even appear in the bibliography when cited explicitly, though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myjournal,
  journaltitle = {Journal of Interesting Things},
  publisher    = {Someone},
  options      = {dataonly},
}
@article{myarticle1,
  crossref = {myjournal},
  title    = {That thing},
  author   = {Martypants, Susan},
  year     = {2019},
}
@article{myarticle2,
  crossref = {myjournal},
  title    = {That other thing},
  author   = {Rofessor, Peter},
  year     = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{myarticle1,myarticle2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

If you don't want to establish this additional parent-child relation it may be better to choose a different tool for the job: [Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182648/cicada) suggested `@xdata` containers in the [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560565/unwanted-item-in-reference-list-when-using-crossref-with-biber#comment1413902_560565). [The `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) explains `xdata` as follows (§2.2.3 *Special Fields*, p. 31)

> This field inherits data from one or more `@xdata` entries. Conceptually, the `xdata`
> field is related to `crossref` and `xref`: `crossref` establishes a logical parent/child relation and inherits data; `xref` establishes as logical parent/child relation
> without inheriting data; `xdata` inherits data without establishing a relation. The
> value of the `xdata` may be a single entry key or a separated list of keys. See §3.13.6
> for further details.

And that seems a great fit: `xdata` is `crossref` sans the parent-child relation that caused the undesired behaviour in the first place.

It should be noted, however, that `@xdata` entries can't appear in the bibliography themselves and can't usefully be cited. Furthermore, the field inheritance with `@crossref` can take into account the entry types of the parent and child entries and can set up rules like the `title` field of a `@collection` parent is inherited as `booktitle` to an `@incollection` child. This is not possible (and does not make sense) for `@xdata`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@xdata{myjournal,
  journaltitle = {Journal of Interesting Things},
  publisher    = {Someone},
}
@article{myarticle1,
  xdata    = {myjournal},
  title    = {That thing},
  author   = {Martypants, Susan},
  year     = {2019},
}
@article{myarticle2,
  xdata    = {myjournal},
  title    = {That other thing},
  author   = {Rofessor, Peter},
  year     = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{myarticle1,myarticle2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

In this particular case all standard styles will ignore the `publisher` field for `@article`s, so you are only inheriting one field, namely the `journal(title)`. Single-field inheritance can also be modelled with `@string` entries. (But of course that is not an option if you want to inherit multiple fields at once.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@string{myjournal = {Journal of Interesting Things}}
@article{myarticle1,
  journal  = myjournal,
  title    = {That thing},
  author   = {Martypants, Susan},
  year     = {2019},
}
@article{myarticle2,
  journal  = myjournal,
  title    = {That other thing},
  author   = {Rofessor, Peter},
  year     = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{myarticle1,myarticle2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

All of the posted example produce

[image: [Mar19] Susan Martypants. “That thing”. In: Journal of Interesting Things (2019).//[Rof20] Peter Rofessor. “That other thing”. In: Journal of Interesting Things (2020).]

Answer (score 1):

Manuel Weinkauf's comment was indeed the solution:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,mincrossrefs=99]{biblatex}
```

I'm adding it as an answer so the question can be closed.